# cURL Use input from user as url

Tags: bash, curl

I want to let a user input a URL to send a request to but I get either
`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`
or
`curl: no URL specified!`

The relevant code looks like this

```
read -p 'Destination: ' URL

curl -X "${REQ}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '${DATA}' "${URL}"
```

I have tried all variations of quotes and curly brackets I could think of

I'm new to this so I'd be grateful if you could explain it a little more in depth

Comment: Why do you have ${DATA} in single quotes?

Comment: You could try `--url "${URL}"`, but as @Roadowl points out, I bet the real problem is that you place single (`'`) quotes around `${DATA}`. You should replace the single quotes around `${DATA}` with double quotes.